# how to get different input names set by time in request

Tags: php, laravel

I have a template that can add new options, that is, an input pattern is followed. I can not put the same name in the inputs, so each name is set with a time function, for example: programmer [prog_id] [123123]. Where the number is set by time. I need to get these names in a Request created by me, but I do not know how to reference them there, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Store them in a variable.

Comment: dd(Input::all()) in your controller

Comment: Or `request()->all()`

Comment: $progIds = $request->input('prog_id'); dd($progIds);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add code next time so we will be able you help reformat and explain easily.

you can get all the inputs in the POST

```
$input = $request->input();
```

and then you will have multi dimensional array that you can iterate, and get the dates by the keys

if i understand correctly, so you will have in POST structure like that:

```
$input = [
     prog_id = [
          time_1 = value1,
          time_2 = value2,
     ]
]
```

and then iteration like that:

```
foreach($input['prog_id'] AS $time=>$value) {
     // here you will have the $time 
}
```

for more info check :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests

Comment: how can I add rules inside the foreach for each key?

Comment: what do you mean by saying "rules" ... which rules?

Comment: my FormRequest, I want to enforce validations

Comment: what do you want want to validate?